# Does WiPy Pysense Device will connect with Other Bluetooth Sensor Devices.?

Tags: bluetooth, sensors

Does the Pysense(WiPy) device will connect and get service from any other Bluetooth Sensor Devices available in the market.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can connect any Bluetooth sensor with mac address using

```
bluetooth = Bluetooth()
bluetooth.start_scan(5)
while bluetooth.isscanning():
adv = bluetooth.get_adv()
if adv:
if(str(binascii.hexlify(adv.mac).decode()) == '78a50454b267'):
conn = bluetooth.connect(adv.mac)
print(type(conn))
```